# Send data form via redux-form and reducer and action creator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

**Hello,
How send the value of fields of my redux form ? Indeed, I need to send the values of fields of my form in database with a reducer and actionCreator.**

***My form :***

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';

class myformClass extends React.Component {
 render(){
  return(
    <form>
      <Field
        name="inputName"
        ref="inputName"
        hintText="Le nom du flux" 
        floatingLabelText="Nom du input" 
        component={renderTextField} 
        fullWidth={true}
      />
      <Field
        label="inputComment" 
        name="inputComment"
        ref="inputComment"
        hintText="La description du input"
        floatingLabelText="Commentaire" 
        component={renderTextareaField} 
      />
    </form>
  )
 }
}

export default withRouter(reduxForm({
    form: 'myForm'
})(myformClass))
```

***In my index app, I imported "reducer in redux-form":***

```
import { reducer as reduxFormReducer } from 'redux-form'
```

***I combined the reducers :***

```
let allReducers = combineReducers({form: reduxFormReducer })
```

***I created a action type :***

```
export const FORM_ADD = 'FORM_ADD'
```

***I created too a action creator :***

```
export function addForm(dataForm) {
  return {
     type: types.FORM_ADD ,
     data: {
       INPUT_NAME: dataForm.inputName, 
       INPUT_COMMENT: dataForm.inputComment
     }
  }
}
```

**But Now, i don't know, how should I retrieve and send the value of my form with my action creator and the reducer. I know that I have to recover the value of my form and then send it.**

***For information, I was able to recover the value of my redux-form by doing this :***

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';

class myformClass extends React.Component {

  static contextTypes = {store: PropTypes.object}

  getValMyForm = () => {
    const { store } = this.context
    const state = store.getState()
    let valueFormFLow = getFormValues('myForm')(state)
    return valueFormFLow;
  }
}

export default withRouter(reduxForm({
    form: 'myForm'
})(myformClass))
```

**I need Your HELP PLEASEEEEEE and I'm sorry for my english!!!  :)**

Comment: Can you clarify: Do you want to SEND the form data (that the user has already filled in) so that you can store it in a database?  OR is it that you would like to LOAD data FROM a database into your form? (Pre-fill the form fields with existing data)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the `reduxForm` function on your component, Redux-From  automatically gives you a `handleSubmit` function, which you can pass a function. That function will, when you submit the form, be given an object where all the form values are available by their key (the `name` property).

For example (runnable **[JSFiddle demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/jonahe/4non6918/2/)**) :

```js
const MyForm = ({handleSubmit}) => (
 <form onSubmit={ handleSubmit((formData) => console.log(formData)) } >
   <div>
     First Name
     <Field name={`firstName`} component='input' type='text' /><br />
     Last Name
     <Field name={`lastName`} component='input' type='text' /><br />
    </div>
   <input type="submit" value="submit" />
  </form>
)

const MyTestForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'myForm'
})(MyForm);

// END EXAMPLE
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <MyTestForm />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

So in this simple form example, if I filled out the the first and second fields with "Test1" and "Test2", then when I press the submit-button I will get a console message with `{firstName: "Test1", lastName: "Test2"}`.

If you had an action dispatch, and/or an API-call that you wanted to run instead, then you would just pass another function to `handleSubmit`.

Comment: Your're welcome! :) By the way: If you add the `javascript` tag to your question, your code examples will get the proper syntax highlighting (like the way the code has different colors in my answer).